# Query MDX Cubo OLAP

Tags: mdx

Necesito crear una query MDX para obtener el número de clientes diferentes de un determinado periodo.

En el cubo tengo la medida Customer Number que está definida como distinct count CUSTOMER_ID.
Necesito calcular esa medida en dos periodos de tiempo:

- Periodo 1: Ejemplo:1-1-2020 al 31-12-2020.
- Periodo 2: Ejemplo 1-1-2019 al 31-12-2019.

He intentado lo siguiente pero no obtengo resultados:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[customerNumber] AS 
    ({[Date.default].Lag(30):[Date.default]}, [Measures].[Customer Number]) 
MEMBER [Measures].[customerNumberOld] AS 
   ({[Date.default].Lag(366+30):[Date.default].Lag(30)}, [Measures].[Customer Number])

SELECT
      {[Measures].[customerNumber], [Measures].[customerNumberOld]} ON 0,
       [Date.default].[2020].[3].[8].[31] ON 1
FROM [Customer Sales]
```

Muchas gracias.